# How to Block a Mobile Device Using Powershell in Exchange

Tags: powershell, mobile, exchange-server

I am using the below code to try and block a mobile device from accessing exchange.

```
$deviceID = $mobileDevices[[int]$menuSelect].DeviceID
Set-CASMailbox -Identity $username -ActiveSyncBlockedDeviceIDs @{Add="$deviceID"}
$MobileDevices[[int]$menuSelect].DeviceAccessState = 'Blocked'
```

But get this warning:

```
WARNING: The command completed successfully but no settings of 'chris.domain/Domain Sites/Pre/John Tar' have been modified.
```

And nothing actually gets blocked.

If I run the code like the below then it does block that single device but unblocks any other devices blocked previously.

```
$deviceID = $mobileDevices[[int]$menuSelect].DeviceID
Set-CASMailbox -Identity $username -ActiveSyncBlockedDeviceIDs $deviceID
$MobileDevices[[int]$menuSelect].DeviceAccessState = 'Blocked'
```

How can I add blocked devices without clearing the old ones?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

so what's your `$menuSelect`? Are you actually getting some kind of menu somewhere - on screen, in the GUI - where you're selecting a number? When you run the script and make your selection, is `$menuselect` actually getting populated with a number? And if it is, is `$deviceID` also getting populated?

Use Powershell IDE or VSCode or something to create a breakpoint on that first line and run it in debug mode and check the values in the variables. Otherwise add some output lines in your script to see if the variables are getting populated.

```bsh
$deviceID = $mobileDevices[[int]$menuSelect].DeviceID
write-host "selection = $menuselect - DeviceID = $DeviceID - User = $username"
Set-CASMailbox -Identity $username -ActiveSyncBlockedDeviceIDs @{Add="$deviceID"}
$MobileDevices[[int]$menuSelect].DeviceAccessState = 'Blocked'
```

If the output looks ok, then run the `Set-CasMailbox` command exactly as you have it here, but replacing the variables with the actual values you saw in the `write-host` or debug output.

By the way, I suspect it's the `@{Add="$deviceID"}` that's the problem. If it looks like the values are ok, what happens if you run it without the quotation marks?

The reason that your second command removes any previously blocked devices is that `ActiveSyncBlockedIds` is a multi-valued attribute, and your second command is simply blowing the existing entries away rather than appending another ID to it. That's why it needs to be done with the `@{Add=..}` method